# AssertionError in test findByActive_ActiveProductsExist

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm experiencing an issue with a test case in my `ProductRepositoryTest` class. The test case `findByActive_ActiveProductsExist` is failing with an `AssertionError`. Here is the error message:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expecting ArrayList:
[Product [id=2, productType=Scanner, productDescription=Scanner de alta resolución, productBrand=Canon, productModel=Canoscan 9000F Mark II, productSerialNumber=1234567890ABCDEF, productTechnicalFeatures=Resolución óptica de 9600 x 9600 ppp, productUsageStatus=EN_USO, productLocation=Oficina principal, assignedUserProduct=1, productPurchaseDate=1969-12-31, active=true, status=Activo, subscription=null]]
to contain only:
[Product [id=1, productType=PC, productDescription=Potente ordenador de escritorio, productBrand=Dell, productModel=XPS 8900, productSerialNumber=1234567890ABCDEF, productTechnicalFeatures=Intel Core i7, 16GB RAM, 2TB HDD, productUsageStatus=DISPONIBLE, productLocation=Oficina principal, assignedUserProduct=null, productPurchaseDate=1969-12-31, active=true, status=Activo, subscription=null],
Product [id=2, productType=Scanner, productDescription=Scanner de alta resolución, productBrand=Canon, productModel=Canoscan 9000F Mark II, productSerialNumber=1234567890ABCDEF, productTechnicalFeatures=Resolución óptica de 9600 x 9600 ppp, productUsageStatus=EN_USO, productLocation=Oficina principal, assignedUserProduct=1, productPurchaseDate=1969-12-31, active=true, status=Activo, subscription=null]]
but could not find the following element(s):
[Product [id=1, productType=PC, productDescription=Potente ordenador de escritorio, productBrand=Dell, productModel=XPS 8900, productSerialNumber=1234567890ABCDEF, productTechnicalFeatures=Intel Core i7, 16GB RAM, 2TB HDD, productUsageStatus=DISPONIBLE, productLocation=Oficina principal, assignedUserProduct=null, productPurchaseDate=1969-12-31, active=true, status=Activo, subscription=null]]
```

The test case is intended to verify that the `findByActive` method in the `ProductRepository` returns the correct list of active products. However, the assertion is failing because the expected list is not found in the actual list.

I noticed that there are differences between the input and output IDs. The `activeProduct1` has an expected ID of 1, but the output shows an ID of 2. Similarly, the `activeProduct2` has an expected ID of 2, but the output shows an ID of 4.

Here is the code for reference:

```java
package com.saajf.manager.eewaapro;
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.List;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.TestEntityManager;
import com.saajf.manager.eewaapro.domain.entities.Product;
import com.saajf.manager.eewaapro.infrastructure.repositories.ProductRepository;
@DataJpaTest
@Transactional
public class ProductRepositoryTest {
@Autowired
private ProductRepository productRepository;
@Autowired
private TestEntityManager entityManager;
@BeforeEach
void setUp() {
// Limpiar los datos de prueba antes de cada prueba
productRepository.deleteAll();
}
@AfterEach
void tearDown() {
// Limpiar los datos de prueba después de cada prueba
productRepository.deleteAll();
}
@Test
@Transactional
void findByActive_ActiveProductsExist() {
Product activeProduct1 = new Product();
activeProduct1.setId(1);
activeProduct1 = new Product(1, "PC", "Potente ordenador de escritorio", "Dell", "XPS 8900", "1234567890ABCDEF",
"Intel Core i7, 16GB RAM, 2TB HDD", "DISPONIBLE", "Oficina principal", null, new Date(0), true,
"Activo");
Product activeProduct2 = new Product();
activeProduct2.setId(2);
activeProduct2 = new Product(2, "Scanner", "Scanner de alta resolución", "Canon", "Canoscan 9000F Mark II",
"1234567890ABCDEF", "Resolución óptica de 9600 x 9600 ppp", "EN_USO", "Oficina principal", 1,
new Date(0), true, "Activo");
Product inactiveProduct1 = new Product(3, "Impresora", "Impresora láser monocromática", "HP",
"LaserJet Pro M15w", "1234567890ABCDEF", "Impresión rápida a 19 ppm", "EN_USO", "Almacén", null,
new Date(0), false, "Inactivo");
productRepository.save(activeProduct1);
productRepository.save(activeProduct2);
productRepository.save(inactiveProduct1);
// Verificar el ID asignado al activeProduct1
System.out.println("ID del activeProduct1: " + activeProduct1.getId());
System.out.println("ID del activeProduct2: " + activeProduct2.getId());
List<Product> activeProducts = productRepository.findByActive(true);
for (Product product : activeProducts) {
System.out.println("ID: " + product.getId());
}
assertThat(activeProducts).containsOnly(activeProduct1, activeProduct2);
}
@Test
@Transactional
void findByProductSerialNumber_ProductExists() {
Product product = new Product();
product.setProductSerialNumber("SN223686007");
product.setProductType("Electronics");
product.setProductDescription("Personal Computer");
product.setProductBrand("Apple");
product.setProductModel("MacBook Pro");
product.setProductTechnicalFeatures("M1 chip, 8GB RAM, 256GB SSD");
product.setProductUsageStatus("Nuevo");
product.setProductLocation("Office");
product.setAssignedUserProduct(2);
product.setProductPurchaseDate(Date.valueOf("2023-05-11"));
product.setActive(false);
product.setStatus("EN_USO");
entityManager.merge(product);
entityManager.flush();
entityManager.clear();
Product foundProduct = productRepository.findByProductSerialNumber("SN223686007");
assertThat(foundProduct).isNotNull();
assertThat(foundProduct.getProductSerialNumber()).isEqualTo("SN223686007");
}
@Test
@Transactional
void findByProductSerialNumber_ProductNotExists() {
// Intentar buscar un producto por un número de serie inexistente
Product foundProduct = productRepository.findByProductSerialNumber("XYZ789");
// Verificar que el producto encontrado sea nulo
assertThat(foundProduct).isNull();
}
}
```

I ran the test cases in the class.